# How to start a local Chart studio instance from Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am having difficulties getting Plotly products up and running locally on my machine. On Plotly's website, many of their products are listed as having open community versions, but I can't find easy and clear guides to getting those versions up and running on my computer.

For this question I will narrow the focus on *Chart studio*.

#### Online Chart studio:

This is Plotly's *Chart studio*, running from their website over at https://plotly.com/chart-studio

[image]

#### But how do I serve Chart studio locally?

I already have the following Plotly components installed:

- `conda install plotly dash`
- `pip install dash-daq chart-studio`
- Falcon from https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/database-connectors/personal-login/

I can serve a local Plotly dashboard, I can dive into a database with Falcon, but I can't seem to serve a local instance of Chart studio.

Comment: Hello, could you find a way to run Chart studio locally at last? Thank you

Comment: Not yet, I stated on other projects and haven't used Plotly again since this question. Would love an answer though.